Pytorch Lightning places model inputs and model to different devices
I'm using Pytorch-lightning 2.4.0. In the following code snippet, lmm is a class inherited from nn.Module which is a wrapper class huggingface model and processor.
class ICVModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, lmm, icv_encoder: torch.nn.Module) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.lmm = lmm
        self.lmm.requires_grad_(False)
        self.icv_encoder = icv_encoder
        self.eos_token = self.lmm.processor.tokenizer.eos_token

    def forward(self, ice_texts, query_texts, answers, images):
        query_answer = [
            query + answer + self.eos_token
            for query, answer in zip(query_texts, answers)
        ]
        query_images = [img[-setting.num_image_in_query :] for img in images]
        query_inputs = self.lmm.process_input(query_answer, query_images)
        query_outputs = self.lmm.model(
            **query_inputs,
            labels=query_inputs["input_ids"],
        )

However, a device mismatch error raised at
query_outputs = self.lmm.model(
        **query_inputs,
        labels=query_inputs["input_ids"],
)

I printed device of inputs.pixel_values.device, self.device, self.lmm.device outside of lmm.model.forward, then I got
rank[0]: cpu cuda:0 cuda:0
rank[1]: cpu cuda:1 cuda:1

In Idefics (self.lmm.model) forward process, when I printed inputs.pixel_values.device and self.device, I got
rank[0]: cuda:0 cuda:0
rank[1]: cuda:0 cuda:1

Besides, I also tried to move pixel_values to correct device, but it still be moved to wrong device in later forward pass.
Error message:
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:1! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper_CUDA__cudnn_convolution)


Providing complete code and run commands helps reproduce the issue.

@TianshuWang Thanks for your reply. I've failed to create a minimal reproducible example. If you are willing to read my full code, please see dev branch .
You can run with following command after get into project directory:
cd dev
python train.py

However, if you want to run my code, you should prepare coco, vqav2 datasets and IDEFICS model. The above downloads have exceeded 20GB.

I've solved this problem.
The key to the problem I did not show in the question I asked, because at that time I did not realize that bitsandbytes and accelerate library would automatically register pre_forward_hook.
It registered an AlignDeviceHook (maybe) at each forward method, which conflicts with the device control of pytorch lightning. When I removed bitsandbytes, everything worked fine.
